# How to create a function that generates an infinite list of an integer-sequence that is defined recursively with two initial numbers X_0 and X_1

Tags: haskell, recursion, sequence

Let's say I have the recursive definition for the following sequence of integers: `a_0 = 5, a_n = 2a_0+3` `->` `5,13,29,61,125...`

I want to use the `iterate` function in Haskell to generate an infinite list of this sequence. To do that I could write the following code:

```hs
intSequence :: Integer -> Integer -> [Integer]
intSequence a0 m = iterate nextNum a0
  where nextNum a = 2*a + m
```

```hs
ghci> let an = intSequence 5 3
ghci> take 5 a
[5,13,29,61,125]
```

---

**Now let's say I instead have the following:**

`X_n = X_n-1 * m_1 + X_n-2 * m_2 + a`

Now I want to create a function called in the following way:

`intSequence x0 x1 m1 m2 a`

that returns an infinite list of a sequence that adheres to the rules of the definition above.

**For example:** For parameters `X0=1, X1=2, m1=2, m2=0, a=0` we get `Xn=X_n-1 * 2 + X_n-2 * 0 + 0 = X_n-1 * 2` which gives us `[1,2,4,8,16,...]`

**Another example:** For parameters `X0=0, X1=1, m1=1, m2=1, a=0` we get the Fibonacci-sequence `X_n = X_n-1 * 1 + X_n-2 * 1 + 0 = X_n-1 + X_n-2` which gives us `[0,1,1,2,3,5,8,...]`

How can I implement this `intSequence` function using `iterate`?

I tried the following which does not work as intended:

```hs
intSequence :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> [Integer]
intSequence x0 x1 m1 m2 a = x0:x1:iterate (nextNum x0) x1
  where
    nextNum x0' x1' = x1'*m1 + x0'*m2 + a
```

```hs
ghci> a = intSequence 0 1 1 1 0
ghci> take 10 a
[0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
```

Which obviously is incorrect and logically so as I never change what `x0` and `x1` are. I think I need to use recursion somehow but I just can't figure out how. Should I maybe not use `iterate` at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is much easier to do with recursion:

```hs
-- helper function for recursion
intSequence' :: (Integral a) => (a, a) -> a -> a -> a -> [a]
-- p2 is X_n-2 and p1 is X_n-1
intSequence' (p2, p1) m1 m2 a =
    -- recurse using X_n-1 as new X_n-2 and current term as new X_n-1
    cur:intSequence' (p1, cur) m1 m2 a
    -- calculate the current term in the sequence
    where cur = p1 * m1 + p2 * m2 + a

-- set previous terms correctly and prepend them to the sequence
intSequence :: (Integral a) => a -> a -> a -> a -> a -> [a]
intSequence x0 x1 m1 m2 a = x0:x1:intSequence' (x0, x1) m1 m2 a
```

Comment: Ah of course, this is so much easier and rather trivial now that I've seen it... Thank you very much!